# Changing from one language to another on a video file using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, language

I have a video file with Spanish language, but the lang flag on the file is 'eng' for English.

Trying to find a way to change the language flag to `spa` for Spanish before I process this file. I have not downloaded FFmpeg yet until I know I can use this app to change the lang.

Anybody know if FFmpeg had this capability, and if not, is there another tool I can use?

Any information is much appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by “…way to change the language flag to `spa` for Spanish before I process this file.” There are audio flags and subtitle flags. If the file contains the `spa` flag for audio or subtitles, FFmpeg can be used to select the `spa` flag for processing. But without knowing the details of what you are hoping to achieve, not much advice an be provided here.